# Interval of Convergence of a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

given that a power series is centered at $x=3$ and knowing that it covnerges at $x=5$ and diverges at $x=0$ what conclusions can we make about the interval of convergence for the series?

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you know about intervals of convergence?  What has you stuck?

Comment: well I know the upper bound on the interval will be 5, but what about the lower bound?

Comment: Actually, you don't know the upper bound is $5$.  You *do* know that the upper bound is *at least* $5$.

Comment: What is the radius of convergence.  And how do you get from radius of convergence to an interval of convergence?

Comment: I dont know the radius of convergence, or is there a way to calculate it from the information i have

Comment: In general what is the radius of convergence? Write the definition out, internalize it and then this is a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

The radius to convergence is greater or equal $2$ and less than or equal $3$

The interval of convergence includes $(1,5]$ and in contained in $(0,6]$

Comment: what does it mean to be cotnained in (0,5)

Comment: and can you explain how you got this answer

Comment: It's contained in $(0, 6]$, not $(0, 5]$, since the radius is between $2$ and $3$.

Comment: since the center is 3 and you have convergent at 5 that means the radius convergent is greater or equal to 5-3=2. Also since at x=0 we have divergence, that means the radius of convergence is less than or equal 3-0=3. Contained in (0,6] means it is a subset of (0,6], – Mohammad Riazi-Kermani 8 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Then the radius of convergence is at least $|3-5|=2$ and at most $|3-0|=3$